# What does 'apt-get install update' do?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash

I saw this snippet in some installation instructions:

```
$ apt-get install update
```

I know what `apt-get install XXXX` does and I know what `apt-get update` does, but I can't find any info on what this combined statement does. What does it do?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is no command like this:

```
$ apt-get install update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update
```

Any arguments given after `install` will be taken by `apt-get` as a package name. But since there is no package `update`, it will fail.

Answer (score 37):

It attempts to install the package named "update".

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there in no package called **update** which the command 
`apt-get install update` should install.

May be they meant `apt-get update` which updates the apt cache.